# Error "Expected Receiver of Type" using Java Reflection in Android

Tags: java, reflection

I encounter this error while trying to learn how to use Java reflection

```
Expected receiver of type android.content.pm.PackageManager, but got java.lang.Class<android.content.pm.PackageManager>
```

Code snippet as follows

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageManager");

Method m = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
{
    m = c.getMethod("getInstalledApplications",PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.class);
}

m.setAccessible(true);

List<ApplicationInfo> output = (List<ApplicationInfo>) m.invoke(c,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You'll need to pass an instance of `android.content.pm.PackageManager` as first argument to invoke, not the class object.

Comment: Reflection doesn’t change the fact that you need an instance to invoke an instance method. And there’s no need for `setAccessible(true)` to invoke a `public` method of a `public` class. And the `m.invoke(…)` call should be inside the `if` statement if you don’t want to get a `NullPointerException` on older Android versions. In fact, the entire declaration of `m` can be inside the `if` statement, as there is no need for it outside. If you don’t  use `m` when the condition is not fulfilled, you don’t need to initialize `m` with `null`.

Comment: Hi @JohannesKuhn Can you give an example of passing an instance of PackageManager?

I did this ```PackageManager d = this.getPackageManager``` instead of ```Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageManager");```

I also changed this ```m = c.getMethod("getInstalledApplications",PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.class);``` to ```m = c.getMethod("getInstalledApplications",int.class);```

Comment: Change `m.invoke(c,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)` to `m.invoke(d, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)`. The first argument to `invoke` is the object to invoke the method on.